# Why can't I get SASS/Bourbon to compile?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, bourbon

I am new to SASS. I am using this as a guide to learn Bourbon -

http://www.git-tower.com/learn/bourbon-neat-bitters/getting-ready/introduction

I followed all the instructions and it displays fine on my local machine. But when I edit _layout.scss, it doesn't compile to styles.css. I installed Compass and had it watch the project folder, but same results. My changes won't take.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: You should post more of your and your file structure to get a answer. _layout.scss is a partial. Partials do not compile into CSS but should be imported in your project file (styles.css). Running `compass clean` removes generated files and the sass cache.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely more of a sass importing/file-name issue than anything specifically with bourbon. I'd check out http://sass-lang.com/guide . Sass-lang put together a really nice guide to sass that includes things like imports, etc.

Also, Compass app can bring some things to the party that can conflict with Bourbon. I'd recommend using the sass app or a desktop app like https://prepros.io which can be easier starting out.

Hope this helps